# PHP MVC Boton submit no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mvc

tengo un problema, tengo una tabla muy grande así que decidi usar AJAX para que se utilicen como filtro, es decir la tabla solo mostrará datos filtrados

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#search_apat, #search_amat, #search_ife').change(function(){
        var search_apat = $('#search_apat').val();
        var search_amat = $('#search_amat').val();
        var search_ife = $('#search_ife').val();
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("paterno", search_apat);
        datos.append("materno", search_amat);
        datos.append("elector", search_ife);       
        $.ajax({
          url:'vistas/modulos/padron/search.php',
          method:"POST",
          data: datos,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success:function(respuesta){
            if(!respuesta.error) {
              $('#tablaPadron').html(respuesta);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Estoy trabajando PHP MVC, en la funcion del controlador por medio de un ECHO refleja la tabla que contiene un boton por renglon el cual abre un modal-dialog de Bootstrap, el cual tendra un formulario para edicion de la base de datos

```
public function validarPadronController($busquedaPadron){

    $datosController = $busquedaPadron;

    $respuesta = GestorPadronModel::validarPadronModel($datosController, "hillo", "firmas");
            echo '
            <table id="tablaPadron" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>                     
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>A Paterno</th>
                  <th>A Materno</th>
                  <th>Clave Elector</th>
                  <th>Folio IFE</th>
                  <th>Firmo</th>                      
                  <th>Editar</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>';
        foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item) {
                echo'

                <tr>
                    <td>'.$item["nombres"].'</td>               
                    <td>'.$item["apat"].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$item["amat"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$item["clave"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$item["folio"].'</td>                                         
                    <td>'.$item["firmo"].'</td>                 
                    <td><a href="#listado'.$item["id"].'" data-toggle="modal"><span class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil quitarSuscriptor"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
                <div id="listado'.$item["id"].'" class="modal fade">

                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-content" id="formulariosMedium">

                        <div class="modal-header titulos">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><h3>X</h3></button>
                            <h2> Editar Datos de Electores</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body fieldset">
                            <form class="formss" method="post">
                                <input name="edit_iden" type="hidden" value="'.$item["iden"].'">
                                <h3>Datos Personales</h3>
                                <hr>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row nombres">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ">
                                        <label for="edit_nombre">Nombre</label>
                                        <input type="text" value="'.$item["nombres"].'" name="edit_nombre" id="edit_nombre" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ">
                                        <label for="edit_apat">A Paterno<span></span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="'.$item["apat"].'" name="edit_apat" id="edit_apat" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 ">
                                        <label for="edit_amat">A Materno<span></span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="'.$item["amat"].'" name="edit_amat" id="edit_amat" readonly>
                                    </div>                                      
                                </div>                      
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <label for="edit_noCelular">Celular <span></span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="'.$item["celular"].'" name="edit_noCelular" maxlength="10" id="edit_noCelular">                   
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <label for="edit_noCelular2">Celular 2 <span></span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="'.$item["tel2"].'" name="edit_noCelular2" maxlength="10" id="edit_noCelular2">                    
                                    </div>                                          
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <label for="edit_correo">Correo Electrónico <span></span></label>
                                        <input type="email" value="'.$item["correo"].'" name="edit_correo" id="edit_correo">
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <label for="edit_facebook">Facebook <span></span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="'.$item["facebook"].'" name="edit_facebook" id="edit_facebook">                   
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                                          
                                <h3>Credencial de Elector</h3>
                                <hr>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <label for="edit_claveElec">Clave Elector <span></span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="'.$item["clave"].'" name="edit_claveElec" maxlength="18" id="edit_claveElec" readonly>                    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <label for="edit_folio">Folio <span></span></label>
                                        <input type="text" value="'.$item["folio"].'" name="edit_folio"  id="edit_folio" required>                  
                                    </div>                                                      
                                </div>
                                <h3>Firmo Iniciativa</h3>
                                <hr>
                                <br>                                    
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <label for="edit_iniciativa">Firmó <span></span></label>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="edit_firma" id="edit_firma" value="SI"';if($item["firmo"] == "SI"){echo "checked disabled";} echo'>SI</label>
                                        </div>              
                                    </div>                                                  
                                </div>                                                                  
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">                                  
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bt-lg" value="Editar">  
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary bt-lg btn-group-justified" data-dismiss="modal" id="editar">TEST</button>

                            </form>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger bt-lg btn-group-justified" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
        }       

    }
```

El problema es que el boton submit no hace nada, quiero que ejecute la siguiente funcion para edicion

```
public function editarPadron(){

    if(isset($_POST["edit_nombre"])){

        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s*[a-zA-Z]*)*[a-zA-Z]+$/', $_POST["edit_nombre"], $nombreError) &&
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s*[a-zA-Z]*)*[a-zA-Z]+$/', $_POST["edit_apat"],
            $apatError) &&
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s*[a-zA-Z]*)*[a-zA-Z]+$/', $_POST["edit_amat"],
            $amatError) &&                 
           preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST["edit_noCelular"], $noCelularError) &&
           preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST["edit_noCelular2"], $noCelular2Error) &&                
           preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s*[a-zA-Z]*)*[a-zA-Z]+$/', $_POST["edit_facebook"],
            $faceError) &&
           preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["edit_claveElec"], $claveElectError) &&
           preg_match('/^[A-Z]+$/', $_POST["edit_firma"], $firmaError) &&
           preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST["edit_folio"], $folioError) &&                  
           preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $_POST["edit_correo"], $correoError)){

            $datosController =array("iden"=>$_POST["edit_iden"],
                                    "noCelular"=>$_POST["edit_noCelular"],
                                    "noCelular2"=>$_POST["edit_noCelular2"],
                                    "facebook"=>$_POST["edit_facebook"],
                                    "claveElect"=>$_POST["edit_claveElec"],
                                    "folios"=>$_POST["edit_folio"],
                                    "firma"=>$_POST["edit_firma"],
                                    "correo"=>$_POST["edit_correo"]);

            $respuesta = GestorPadronModel::editarPadronModel($datosController, "firmas");

                if($respuesta == "success"){
                    echo"<script>
                        swal({
                          title: 'Está a Punto de Editar un Elector',
                          text: '¿Es Correcto?',
                          type: 'warning',
                          showCancelButton: true,
                          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                          confirmButtonText: 'SI, Editar!'
                        }).then(function () {
                          swal(
                            'Editado!',
                            'Elector Fue Editado Correctamente!!',
                            'success'
                          );
                          window.location.href ='listado';
                        });
                        </script>";

                }
                if($respuesta == "error"){
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                        swal(
                        'Fallo...',
                        'Elector NO Fue Editado Correctamente!',
                        'error'
                        );</script>";
                }   
        }else{
            $vacia =""; 
            if (empty($nombreError)){$vacia ='NOMBRE';}else
            if (empty($apatError)){$vacia ='APELLIDO PATERNO';}else
            if (empty($amatError)){$vacia ='APELLIDO MATERNO';}else
            if (empty($noCelularError)){$vacia ='CELULAR';}else
            if (empty($noCelular2Error)){$vacia ='CELULAR 2';}else                  
            if (empty($faceError)){$vacia ='FACEBOOK';}else
            if (empty($claveElectError)){$vacia ='CLAVE DE ELECTOR';}else
            if (empty($folioError)){$vacia ='FOLIO';}else
            if (empty($firmaError)){$vacia ='FIRMA';}else
            if (empty($correoError)){$vacia ='CORREO';}

                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    swal(
                        'NO es Posible Editar!!!',
                        'El Campo ".$vacia."  NO cumple con lo requerido, Favor de Verificarlo!',
                        'error'
                );</script>";
            }
        }       
    }
```

Alguna Sugerencia???

gracias

el siguiente es codigo es donde tengo la base de datos

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION["validar"]){

  header("location:ingreso");

  exit();

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nuevo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/css/forms.css">

</head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#search_apat, #search_amat, #search_ife').change(function(){
        var search_apat = $('#search_apat').val();
        var search_amat = $('#search_amat').val();
        var search_ife = $('#search_ife').val();
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append("paterno", search_apat);
        datos.append("materno", search_amat);
        datos.append("elector", search_ife);       
        $.ajax({
          url:'vistas/modulos/padron/search.php',
          method:"POST",
          data: datos,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success:function(respuesta){
            if(!respuesta.error) {
              $('#tablaPadron').html(respuesta);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <?php include "vistas/modulos/cabecera.php"; ?>
      </div>          
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <h1>Listado Hermosillo</h1>
                <hr>              
          </div>
      </div>
      <h3>Busqueda</h3>
      <hr>      
      <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">           
              <label for="search_apat"> A Paterno: </label>
              <input id="search_apat" class="form-control search_apat" type="text"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
              <label for="search_amat"> A Materno: </label>
              <input id="search_amat" class="form-control search_amat" type="text"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
              <label for="search_ife"> Clave Elector: </label>
              <input id="search_ife" class="form-control search_ife" type="text"></input>
            </div>
          </div>                   
      </div>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">     
          <?php
          $crearPerfil = new GestorPadron();
          $crearPerfil -> editarPadron();
          ?>                     
                <div class="table-responsive">

                <table id="tablaPadron" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>                     
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Apellidos</th>
                      <th>Clave Elector</th>
                      <th>Firmo</th>                      
                      <th>Editar</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
              </div>             
            </div>  
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

el search.php que llama AJAX

```
[![<?php 
    require_once "../../../controladores/gestorPadron.php";
    require_once "../../../modelos/gestorPadron.php";

    class Ajax{

        public $busquedaPadron =array();
        public function bucarElectorAjax(){

            $datos =$this->busquedaPadron;

            $respuesta = GestorPadron::validarPadronController($datos);

            echo $respuesta;
        }
    }




if (isset($_POST\["paterno"\])|| isset($_POST\["materno"\])|| isset($_POST\["elector"\])) {

        $a = new Ajax();
        $a-> busquedaPadron = array("paterno"=>$_POST\["paterno"\],
                                    "materno"=>$_POST\["materno"\],
                                    "elector"=>$_POST\["elector"\]);
        $a-> bucarElectorAjax();

}

 ?>][1]][1]
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. ¿La función `editarPadron` se ejecuta? no veo en tu código dónde se invoca.

Comment: Por medio de ajax no puedes ejecutar funciones de php, puedes trabajar esto usando datos dentro de POST o GET, durante la ejecución del archivo php captures este dato que enviaste y en base a eso mande llamar la función algo como `if($_POST['search'] == 1) editarPatron()`

Comment: agregue mas informacion a la pregunta